# Error: No such object: my-nginx

Tags: linux, bash

Всем привет! Пишу скрипт, в скрипте переменной задаю вывод команды, но в скрипте она не отрабатывает, а вот если в командной строке запустить, то работает, наверное нужно экранировать символы, вот скрипт:

```
sshpass -e ssh -tt -p $port $name@$server << EOF
docker ps -a
ipv6=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.GlobalIPv6Address }}" my-nginx)
echo $ipv6
exit
EOF
```

Команда, которая не работает:

```
ipv6=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.GlobalIPv6Address }}" my-nginx)
```

Ошибка: Error: No such object: my-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, нужно подключаться так:

```
ssh -T vivek@server1<<'ENDSSH'
var=$(date)
echo "$var"
ENDSSH
```